# how to get i of loop in sql request

Tags: python, mysql

i want to fill the database so i have a subgroup(sous group) table and member table.
every subgroups has an liste of member so i can fill the subgroups but i want to to fill every subgroups with members
but i cannot get the i of loop in the sql request

```
def Generate_add_new_sous_groupe():
    groupDictList=Get_Group_and_member()
    for groupItem in ( groupDictList):
                #print('////////////////////////////////////////////////////////')
                print(groupItem['group_name'])
                print(groupItem['members'])
                print('////////////////////////////////////////////////////////')

            print 

            sql = "INSERT INTO sous_group (sg_name,id_gr ) VALUES (%s,(select id_gr from groupe where groupe.id_gr=1))"
            val = [
                  groupItem['group_name'],

            ]
            cursor.executemany(sql, val)
            for x in range(1, 33):

                sql1 = "INSERT INTO member (M_name, Id_SG  ) VALUES (%s,(select Id_SG from sous_group where sous_group.Id_SG= %s)) "                                   
                val = [
                        ((str(groupItem['members'])),x),
                ]
                cursor.executemany(sql1, val)
             db.commit() 

raise errorclass(errno, errval)
```

IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'Id_SG' cannot be null")

Comment: You are trying to insert M_name and Id_SG (2 fields) but passing just one as parameter.

Comment: str(groupItem['members']) for M_name  and select Id_SG from sous_group where sous_group.Id_SG= %s (x) for  Id_SG

Comment: i know it can works for M_name but the problem for me is for Id_SG